# Grouping numbers that are "close to each other"

Tags: algorithms

Let's say you have a set of numbers S and you want to obtain subsets of $S$, $s_1,s_2,\ldots, s_i$, where $i < N$.

Is there a particular operation that will group the numbers that are "close to each other"?

I will give an example to clarify the question:

Let's say you have a set $S$ which contains $\{1.4, 2, 2.5, 2.7, 14, 16, 49, 57, 58\}$

And let's say that you can have maximum of $N=4$ subsets.

So, you might end up with a result that looks like this:

$s_1 = \{1.4, 2, 2.5, 2.7\}$
$s_2 = \{14, 16\}$
$s_3 = \{49\}$
$s_4 = \{57, 58\}$

I am looking for either the name what such a problem would be called (which I can then use to research and write an algorithm).  If you can provide a simple solution, even better.

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: set-theory is not the tag. The algorithm will depend on what you mean by "close".

Comment: I agree that it depends on what I mean by "close".  I am looking for an algorithm that at least generally does what I'm asking so I have a starting point.  Right now, I don't even know what to call this.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You are just looking for the $N$ maximal values of $x_{i+1}-x_i$ after sorting your set $S = \{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$. I doubt this has some name.

Comment: Sounds like "clustering"...

Comment: The differences belonging to your example are 0.6, 0.5, 0.2, 11.3, 2, 33, 8, 1. The 4 biggest values are 33 (= 49-16), 11.3 (= 14-2.7) and 8 (= 57-49) giving your result.

Comment: Thank J.M. for the name "clustering".  Makes perfect sense and sometimes giving something a name can make all the difference.

Comment: And big thank you to jug for providing the answer.  That is a very elegant solution.  It does not require any recursion or special analysis.  I think that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Jug's answer makes sense, but it's not "the" answer.  In some applications it would not be optimal.  For instance, let S have 100 values in the interval [0,1], 100 values in [2,3], 100 values in [4,5], 100 values in [6,7], and one value of 10.  If the objective is to minimize the sums of squares to the centers of the clusters, 10 must be clustered with the values in [6,7] even though the gap is largest.  It merely turns out in the particular example of the OP, the clustering is so strong that any remotely reasonable algorithm will work.

Comment: @whuber: I agree. That's why I posted it just as a comment. It's maybe "the" most trivial approach (which might be anyway enough for jeffp). @jeffp: Even if you won't implement the methods in the answer of whuber, I'd recommend to accept his answer (or whatever better answer will be posted), as it provides a better solution in general.

Comment: Thanks - I have implemented jug's comment and it is working for some cases, but as whuber pointed it there are cases where it does not do what I would consider to be ideal.  Either way it is a great starting point.  I will probably end up going with what whuber suggested for my final implementation.  Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are many solutions to this problem extant, each rediscovered many times.  Search "statistical clustering methods" or ["cluster analysis."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis)  A particularly nice one for your problem is called ["K-means"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering).  This was rediscovered by cartographers (!) where it is called ["Jenks' method"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenks_Natural_Breaks_Optimization) (and is worth mentioning because it's used by some popular mapping software, so perhaps more people have heard of this than of any other method).  The idea behind K-means is to minimize the population-weighted sum of variances of the subsets.

BTW, the challenge in most clustering algorithms lies in determining the number of clusters; usually that needs to be specified (as $N = 4$ in this example) or at least hinted at by the user.  For instance, there always exists a minimum K-means solution: partition $S$ into singletons.  If you require $i < n$, merge the two nearest neighbors but leave all the other singletons as they are: the sum of variances is then just one-quarter the square of the smallest difference among the $x_i$.

Comment: I remembered "clustering", but forgot "k-means". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a somewhat related operation, *condensation*, in the theory of linear orderings. For example, you can take a linear ordering and identify any two elements $x,y$ which are connected by some finite chain, i.e. there are elements $x = v_1,\ldots,v_n = y$ such that $v_1 < \cdots < v_n$ and there are no elements 'in between', i.e. no $z$ such that $v_i < z < v_{i+1}$. This will compress all copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{N}$ (or its opposite) to a single point.

This particular condensation can be used to (de)construct all countable linear orders, if I remember correctly. There are also some other condensations, take a look at Rosenstein's *Linear orderings*.